# Site search that matches in more than one field

Tags: search

I'm wondering how to conduct a site search that takes search words and matches them in more than one field. So for example if I have an entry with fields that contain the following words:

Description Field: foo

Body Field: bar baz

A search for 'foo', or 'bar', or 'bar baz' finds the entry, but a search for 'foo bar' does not.

I have rebuilt the search index.

Comment: I'm using set entries = craft.entries.search(query).order('score') to conduct the search

Answer (score 1):

`foo bar` implies `foo AND bar` by default.  What you're probably looking for is `foo OR bar`.

If you look at `craft_searchindex`, you can see that keywords for fields are indexed on a per field basis, which is why you'd need the `OR` to search across multiple fields.

You can omit `OR` if you already know the field names ahead of time, though. `field1:foo field2:bar`.

You can see more search syntax options [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/searching).

Comment: No, I am looking for foo AND bar, just as I am looking for bar AND baz. The former are found across two fields whereas the latter is in one field.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Brad. What I am really looking for is a site search solution that an end user can use to search the whole site (which usually involves many sections and fields). So what you are suggesting is that I have to take the search string and apply it across all sections and fields to effectively join them up.

Comment: You can have the search form submit to a custom plugin that does whatever processing/manipulation on the search string it needs to before passing it on to Craft.